# How to check if the model field/property is valid in a View?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

Is it possible to have a check condition in the view if the field in the model is valid?

I have a view page that contains username and password field. There fields are having [Required] attribute in the model class so that this two fields will validate if not supplied.

My goal is to change the css of a label in the view if this field is not valid.

Anyone please advise. Thanks in advance!

Comment: possible duplicate of [show div if unobtrusive validation was invalid and hide it if Valid in MVC 3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10267515/show-div-if-unobtrusive-validation-was-invalid-and-hide-it-if-valid-in-mvc-3)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use jQuery with the unobtrusive validation used by MVC.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10267902/394028) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10267907/394028) should give you two ways you can use